# How to refer to a column in a function

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I was trying to write a function that contains two actions, and the first one includes subsetting a dataframe.

Let's say I have these two dataframes.

```
      ID   Var1
   1   5     3
   2   6     1



      ID   Var2
   1   5     9
   2   6     2
```

And my function is like this

```
mu_fuc = function(df, condition) {
    workingdf = subset(df, condition < 3)

###pass working df to the other action
  }
```

I am aware that for this first action, I can use conditional slicing as a work around. However, as I try to work on the other action, I realized I still have to refer to a column name in an dataframe for another existing function.

I tried as.name(condition), but it did not work.

Thank you for your time. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

---------Update on 12/26-----------

The method using eval worked well for the function once, as below.

```
meta = function(sub_data, y) {
  y <- eval(as.list(match.call())$y, sub_data)
  workingdf <- subset(sub_data, y != 999) ##this successfully grab the column named y in the dataframe## 
  
  meta1 <- metacor(y,  ##this successfully grab the column named y in the dataframe## 
                   n, 
                   data = workingdf,
                   studlab = workingdf$Author_year,
                   sm = "ZCOR",
                   method.tau = "SJ", 
                   comb.fixed = F)
  return(meta1)
```

But somehow the same approach did not work in the following code.

```
mod_analysis = function(meta, moderator){
  workingdf <- meta$data
  moderator <- eval(as.list(match.call())$moderator, workingdf) 
  
  output = metareg(meta, moderator)
  return(output)
}
```

Then it was this error message:

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'moderator' not found
```

I don't know why it worked for the first function but not the second.

Answer (score 3):

One can convert the `condition` from a simple column reference to an expression, enabling the function argument to include the right hand side of an expression instead of hard coding it into the function. This can be accomplished with a couple of functions from the `rlang` package, `enquo()` and `eval_tidy()`.

We'll illustrate this with a subsetting function and the `mtcars` data frame.

```
aSubsetFunction <- function(df,condition){
   require(rlang)
   condition <- enquo(condition)
   rows_value <- eval_tidy(condition, df)
   stopifnot(is.logical(rows_value))
   df[rows_value, ,drop = FALSE]
}
```

The `condition <- enquo(condition)` line quotes the condition expression. The `eval_tidy()` function evaluates the quoted expression, using `df` as a data mask. The output from `eval_tidy()`, `rows_value`, is a vector of logical values (TRUE / FALSE), which we use on the row dimension of the input data frame with the `[` form of the extract operator. We use `stopifnot()` to generate an error if `rows_value` is not a vector of logical values.

We call the function twice to illustrate that it works with multiple columns in the data frame.

```
aSubsetFunction(mtcars,mpg > 25)
aSubsetFunction(mtcars,carb > 4)
```

...and the output:

```
> aSubsetFunction(mtcars,mpg > 25)
Loading required package: rlang
                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Honda Civic    30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
Porsche 914-2  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
Lotus Europa   30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
> aSubsetFunction(mtcars,carb > 4)
               mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
Ferrari Dino  19.7   6  145 175 3.62 2.77 15.5  0  1    5    6
Maserati Bora 15.0   8  301 335 3.54 3.57 14.6  0  1    5    8
```

Using data from the original post, the solution works as follows.

```
df1 <- read.csv(text="ID,Val1
                5,3
                6,1")
df2 <- read.csv(text="ID,Val2
                5,9
                6,2")
aSubsetFunction(df1,Val1 < 3)
aSubsetFunction(df2,Val2 < 3)
```

...and the output:

```
> aSubsetFunction(df1,Val1 < 3)
  ID Val1
2  6    1
> aSubsetFunction(df2,Val2 < 3)
  ID Val2
2  6    2
```

Having illustrated the approach, we can use the order of object evaluation in R to simplify the function down to a single line of R code:

```
aSubsetFunction <- function(df,condition){
   require(rlang)
   df[eval_tidy(enquo(condition), df), ,drop = FALSE]
}
```

...which produces the same output as listed above.

```
> aSubsetFunction(mtcars,mpg > 25)
Loading required package: rlang
                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Honda Civic    30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
Porsche 914-2  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
Lotus Europa   30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
> aSubsetFunction(mtcars,carb > 4)
               mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
Ferrari Dino  19.7   6  145 175 3.62 2.77 15.5  0  1    5    6
Maserati Bora 15.0   8  301 335 3.54 3.57 14.6  0  1    5    8
>
```

### Epilogue: why can't we use variable substitution with subset()?

From an initial look at the question, one might expect that we could resolve the question with the following code.

```
subset2 <- function(df,condition){
   subset(df,df[[condition]] > 4)
}

subset2(mtcars,carb)
```

However, this fails with an object not found error:

```
 Error in (function(x, i, exact) if (is.matrix(i)) as.matrix(x)[[i]] else .subset2(x,  : 
  object 'carb' not found
```

Once again [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/evaluation.html#programming-with-subset) provides an explanation, directly quoting from the documentation for `subset()`.

> This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like [, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument subset can have unanticipated consequences.

**Bottom line:** it's important to understand Base R non-standard evaluation when writing functions to automate one's analysis because the assumptions coded into various R functions can produce unexpected results. This is especially true of modeling functions like `lm()` that rely on `formula()`, as Wickham describes in [Advanced R: wrapping modeling functions](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/evaluation.html#wrapping-modelling-functions).

References: [Advanced R, Chapter 20 section 4](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/evaluation.html), [Chapter 20 section 6](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/evaluation.html#programming-with-subset)

Comment: Very nice answer with good explanations, upvote for it, +1!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and example. However, I was wondering if this would work if I would like to refer to a column within another function that is not subset? So for example, here I tried to subset based on the condition first, then feed the new dataframe to another function using the "condition" (i.e., column name).

Comment: @Chen-Wei - In order to directly respond to your comment I'd need to see an example of what you are trying to accomplish. Generally speaking, however, if all you need to pass is a column name to a function you do not need the expression-oriented solution I posted. Instead, one would simply pass the column name as an argument and use the `[` or `[[` forms of the extract operator to reference it within the function.

Comment: Hi, I was trying to a similar thing that appeared in the link you gave. I was trying to use the function "metareg" inside my own function, but I was not able to let the inner function capture what it needs to capture. So for example, I want it to capture a column called "n" in the dataframe, and used it in a meta-regression.

Comment: I tried to do this by the following codes, but it did not work: 
`mod_analysis = function(meta, condition, env = caller_env()) {
  workingdf <-enexpr(meta$data)
  condition <- enexpr(condition)
  
  output = expr(metareg(!!meta, !!condition))
  expr_print(output)
  eval(output, env)
}`
The error is as follows: Error: `arg` must be a symbol

Comment: @Chen-Wei - this qualifies as a new question. Please post a new question that follows the guidelines in [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including some sample data so we can reproduce the error and determine how to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can try `match.call` with `eval`

```
mu_fuc <- function(df, condition) {
  condition <- eval(as.list(match.call())$condition, df)
  workingdf <- subset(df, condition < 3)
  workingdf
}
```

which enables

```
> mu_fuc(df1, Var1)
  ID Var1
2  6    1

> mu_fuc(df2, Var2)
  ID Var2
2  6    2
```

Comment: Hi, could you check for the updated question in the original post? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this with indexing:

```
#Funtion
mu_fuc = function(df, condition) {
  workingdf <- df[df[[condition]]<3,]
  return(workingdf)
} 
#Apply
mu_fuc(df1,'Var1')
```

Output:

```
mu_fuc(df1,'Var1')
  ID Var1
2  6    1
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 5:6, Var1 = c(3L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2"))
```